# How can I append a new column to a csv file using OpenCSV?

Tags: java, list, csv, opencsv

I am writing data from one csv file to other but I want to append a new **column** to the destination file,
Note that the data of the that column stored in a list,
This The function I worked on, I want to add the appending step

```
private void writeDataToCSVDestinationFile(Path csvPath, Path destPath, String colToNormalize) throws IOException, CsvException {
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(destPath.toString()));
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvPath.toString()));
        List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
          rows= reader.readAll();

    }
```

And the data of the column stored in this list:

```
public static List<BigDecimal> dataAfterNormalization = new ArrayList<>();
```

Please I need a help to do that

Comment: You might try to use [this](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVParserWriter.html#CSVParserWriter-java.io.Writer-com.opencsv.ICSVParser-java.lang.String-) with a subclassed parser that adds an extra column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opencsv + add new column to existing csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467175/opencsv-add-new-column-to-existing-csv)